# firestore not working on Netscape 5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

firestore fetching is working using mobile browsers except to this
(Netscape 5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/20B110 ChannelId(11) Ariver/1.0.11 Griver/2.48.2 AppContainer/1.9.1 GCashDev/5.63.1:616 AliApp(Griver/2.41.0) Language/en MiniProgram -?)

```
i get this using this codenavigator.sayswho= (function(){var ua= navigator.userAgent;var tem;var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=/))/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');}if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)/(\d+)/);if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');}M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];if((tem= ua.match(/version/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);return M.join(' ');})();
```

ive tried adding

enablePersistence({
synchronizeTabs: true
})
your text``your text
in my firestore fetching